# Codeigniter 4: two ci_session cookies

Tags: session-cookies, codeigniter-4

I am using CI 4.4.4. I have a few pages (controllers) that trigger a second ci_session cookie for some reason. Originally I thought it was a filter issue until I noticed two cookies being generated with different controllers. I have a dashboard page that works properly but when I go to my admin or developer controller, a second cookie appears and confuses the system with incomplete session data. As soon as I navigate away from that control, the second cookies disappears. I am using the database driver for my sessions.

I have manually deleted the cookies from the browser (Chrome) and emptied the ci_sessions table and the issue continues to reoccur. The system has been working properly for months so I’m not really sure what could have happened that would cause this. Also, I am using SSL with WAMP server.

Comment: I'd start by checking what _path_ the cookie you are receiving is set to be valid for, it sounds like you might have a discrepancy there.

Comment: Are you meaning the path I set for cookies in my ENV file?

Comment: No, I meant first of all checking on the client side, what path value is actually contained in the Set-Cookie headers. If you get "two" cookies of the same name - then most likely a different path was used in at least one of these responses.

Comment: How do I check this? And how do I correct it? Sorry, I’m new to some of these things.

Comment: It will be in the App\Config\Session.php file

Comment: Browser dev tools, network panel - look at the relevant requests, inspect their headers, and look for the ones setting the / a session cookie.

Comment: *I have a few pages (controllers) that trigger a second ci_session cookie for some reason*: is dashboard login different from admin/developer?